# How to unzip a .zip file on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

After StoreKit downloads the IAP content package it returns an NSURL to me which looks like this:

> file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/45EF2B3A-3CAB-5A44-4B4A-631A122A4299/Library/Caches/BA32BC55-55DD-3AA4-B4AC-C2A456622229.zip/

Despite all sources I found claiming that StoreKit unzips the content package once downloaded, it hands me over a ZIP. This ZIP probably contains the file structure of the content package. But how do I unzip this?

Comment: In App Purchase content downloaded from the app store is not compressed so you do not need to unzip it, you can treat it as a directory (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19660668/897093)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [Zip Foundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) if you are working in Swift language. It's easy to use and one of the best swift library for unzipping a zip file.

Zip:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
let currentWorkingPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
var sourceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
sourceURL.appendPathComponent("file.txt")
var destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
destinationURL.appendPathComponent("archive.zip")
do {
    try fileManager.zipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
} catch {
    print("Creation of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
}
```

UnZip:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
let currentWorkingPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
var sourceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
sourceURL.appendPathComponent("archive.zip")
var destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
destinationURL.appendPathComponent("directory")
do {
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURL,             withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
try fileManager.unzipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
} catch {
    print("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
}
```

If you are using Objective-C then [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) is the best choice for this.

You can unzip using this

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *outputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/ImagesFolder"];

NSString *zipPath = Your zip file path;

[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:outputPath delegate:self];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 9):

There is a great 3rd party tool for zipping/unzipping files for iPhone

https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive

Very simple to use. Hope that helps!!

Edit:

Quick method I created which takes url, downloads the zip and unzips it

```
-(void)downloadAndUnzip : (NSString *)sURL_p : (NSString *)sFolderName_p
{
    dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
    dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(q, ^{
        //Path info
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL_p];
        NSData *data = [NSData  dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSString *fileName = [[url path] lastPathComponent];
        NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        dispatch_async(main, ^


                 {
                       //Write To
                       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
                       NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:sFolderName_p];

                       [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:filePath toDestination:dataPath];

                   });
});

}
```