# unzip contents in-app purchase ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, unzip, iap-hosted-content

apple hosted contents are downloading as .zip in case of in-app purchase.
m trying to unzip these contents but filed to open .zip file with zipArchive.

```
ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
za.delegate = self;
NSString *path = [download.contentURL path];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    NSLog(@"File Exists: %@", path);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"file not exists: %@", path);
}


if( [za UnzipOpenFile:path] ) {
    if( [za UnzipFileTo:dir overWrite:YES] != NO )
    {
        NSLog(@"unzip data success");
        //unzip data success
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"unzip failed");
    }


    [za UnzipCloseFile];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"unzip can't open file");
}
```

output is

File Exists:....path..
unzip cant open file

Rather its working fine if I bundle a .zip file own

```
path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"module.zip"];

ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
za.delegate = self;
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    NSLog(@"File Exists: %@", path);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"file not exists: %@", path);
}


if( [za UnzipOpenFile:path] ) {
    if( [za UnzipFileTo:dir overWrite:YES] != NO )
    {
        NSLog(@"unzip data success");
        //unzip data success
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"unzip failed");
    }


    [za UnzipCloseFile];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"unzip can't open file");
}
```

here out put is

```
File Exists: /var/mobile/Applications/B22970ED-D30A-460A-A0A1-C8458795C370/myApp.app/module.zip

myApp[615:907] 63 entries in the zip file
2013-10-29 18:39:46.012 myApp[615:907] unzip data success
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do not try to unzip package. This is just a folder. You can look at the content using this code:

```
NSArray *tempArrayForContentsOfDirectory =[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[download.contentURL path] error:&error];
```