# Need help unzipping a zip file containing 3000+ files and accessing them later (xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a difficult time unzipping a file containing 3000+ files and then using those files to populate the detailed view of a searchable UITableView.

I have a searchable UITableView that contains information on 3000+ English nouns. If you select a cell from within the table, you’ll be taken to a UIWebView that uses html files to populate additional information about the selected noun. For example, if I were to select the cell containing the word “water,” it would use a file called “water.html” for the detailed UIWebView. If I copy the water.html file to my project (to where it shows up in the left sidebar in xcode), it works exactly how I want it to.

**Screenshots**

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJxee.png (search view)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/EguBE.png (detailed view)

However, if I add 3000+ html files to my project, xcode slows to the point where I can't get anything done. I’m open to alternative suggestions, but one of the solutions I found was to include a .zip file containing those files and find a way to unzip it only when the app is run for the first time or after an update. I also read somewhere that I could have the files copied over during the build phase, but I'm not quite sure what that would entail. I have already made all of the html files using a macro in Excel, so I would prefer to avoid any solutions that involves changing that aspect.

I’ve made a great deal of effort to figure out a solution via Google, but I just haven’t been able to get anything I try to work properly. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have no previous experience in objective-c prior to this, so I do use a lot of borrowed code from online tutorials. It's probably not the most efficient, but it's what I've got in place.

**I’ve already looked at previous Stack Overflow questions that discuss unzipping files.** I have read through dozens of answers with no success. I have tried SSZipArchive, and I already have the files for this in my project. If possible, I would prefer to use this, but I don’t know where or how to implement it.

Answers to questions like this have been very helpful, but I haven’t found one specific enough to my needs to figure it out how to implement it yet.
[How to unzip a .zip file on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105072/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-on-ios)

**The parts I’m struggling to figure out are:**

- How do I execute the unzip process? (Where do I place the code?)
- What directory should I unzip the file to and how? (I’m not familiar with default directory names.)
- How do I change the detailView code to access the directory the html files were unzipped to?

I use an NSArray to populate the UITableView like this:

```
Item *item1 = [Item new];
item1.nounSingular = @"aardvark";
item1.nounPlural = @"aardvarks";
item1.nounType = @"規則";

Item *item2 = [Item new];
item2.nounSingular = @"ability";
item2.nounPlural = @"abilities";
item2.nounType = @"規則";

Item *item3 = [Item new];
item3.nounSingular = @"abroad";
item3.nounPlural = @"なし";
item3.nounType = @"不可算";

Item *item4 = [Item new];
item4.nounSingular = @"absence";
item4.nounPlural = @"absences";
item4.nounType = @"規則";

Item *item5 = [Item new];
item5.nounSingular = @"abstract";
item5.nounPlural = @"abstracts";
item5.nounType = @"規則";

Item *item6 = [Item new];
item6.nounSingular = @"abuse";
item6.nounPlural = @"abuses";
item6.nounType = @"規則";

Item *item7 = [Item new];
item7.nounSingular = @"accelerator";
item7.nounPlural = @"accelerators";
item7.nounType = @"規則";

Item *item8 = [Item new];
item8.nounSingular = @"accent";
item8.nounPlural = @"accents";
item8.nounType = @"規則";

Item *item9 = [Item new];
item9.nounSingular = @"water";
item9.nounPlural = @"なし";
item9.nounType = @"不可算";

items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, nil];
```

Here’s the segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showItemDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        Item *item = nil;

        if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            item = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        ItemDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.item = item;
    }
}
```

Lastly, I refer to the nounSingular identifier I used in the "item" array to load the html file like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:self.item.nounSingular ofType:@"html"]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Whenever possible, please be detailed with explanations if you can. It would really help me out a lot, and I best learn from example. I have a web design background, and I am only about a month or so into building my first app. This is the last issue I need to address before submitting my app for release, so I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Use a 3rd-party zip package (I think there are 2 or 3) and access the files from the zip as you need them, rather than "unzipping" them all.